# How do I Remove Pokemon Online?

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I was told to try `sudo apt-get remove pokemon-online-client` but it says `command not found: pokemon-online-client`. what should I do to remove it?

Comment: Is that the full output? Where are you typing that command?

Comment: Did you install the package pokemon-online-client using apt-get?  Its not in the built in sources (I don't get hits trying to install the package).

Comment: @ will: I used a tar.gz file

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: full out put is 
`[sudo] password for joe: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pokemon-online-client`

I am typing this in the terminal

Comment: You didn't get it from a PPA? Then you can't use deb to manage it... did it come with an uninstaller?

Comment: I don't think so, it cam with an `install.sh`, a `startclient.sh`, and the `README` doesn't say anything about uninstalling, but I will look around. If there isn't one, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded [this program](http://pokemon-online.eu/download) then just remove the folder where you extracted the contents of the `.tar.gz` file to.

Optionally you can run `apt-get autoremove` or try to manually remove the libraries the `install.sh` script installed.